# String to integer conversion using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a two textbox and i want to convert string value such as "apple" and "cat" into appropriate integer value using javascript.

Comment: and what's the appropiate integer value???

Comment: @ClaudioRedi 42 I guess

Comment: what would be the appropiate integer value? zero?

Comment: Huh, i don't understand what you are asking

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `{'apple': 24601, 'cat': 42}[s]`?

Comment: `console.log(parseInt('cat'))` //NaN

Answer (score 2):

Simple...

```
var myInt = "cat";
var converted = parseInt(myInt, 10);
console.log(converted);
>>NaN
```